# SoX FIR one-liner

Tags: shell, audio, sox

I'm trying to apply reverb by convolving with an impulse response in SoX. The following shell script does exactly what I want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# 
# Convolve audio file with and impulse response (IR)
# 
# Usage:
#
#     applyReverb.sh <ir.wav> <audio.wav> <output.wav>

# IR duration (needed for zero-padding to prevent SoX from cutting 
# the resulting audio after applying the FIR filter
IR_DUR=`soxi -D $1`

# read IR from wav, resample it if necessary, make sure is mono
# and save it as plain text (.dat format in SoX). Also reduces gain 
# to prevent clipping later
sox --norm=-10 -c 1 $1 -r 44100 filter.dat

# extract the coeffients (second column, skipping the first 2 lines)
awk 'NR<3{next}{print $2}' filter.dat > filter.txt

# apply reverb using SoX's fir effect (need front zero-padding to for
# the extra samples due to the convolution
sox "|sox $2 -p pad $IR_DUR 0" --norm $3 fir filter.txt
```

***The Question***

How can I do this without the temporary files (filter.*)? I know the answer lies within the pipes, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found what I was looking for. In case anyone out there is interested, this is my solution:

```
sox --norm=-10 -c 1 $1 -r 44100 -t dat - | awk 'NR<3{next}{print $2;}' | sox "|sox $2 -p pad $d $d" --norm $3 fir -
```

Comment: when I run this the output file is not what I expect. It just sounds like a cut off reverb tail.

Comment: @headkit, that's the intended behavior here. A convolution reverb should generate an output that is _just_ the reverb as applied to the audio. Then, you mix the dry and wet signals together to your taste.

That said, I did have to futz around with the solution posted here to get correct results. This only works for applying a _mono_ impulse to a _mono_ audio file. If you need stereo or anything else, you have to split files up and apply the logic individually